# Edge/Firefox OK, Chrome/Opera SLOW windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, opera

I have a new windows 10 computer, Edge and Firefox work fine but chrome and opera keep having timeout errors what are the possible causes of this problem. I also know that opera and chrome have the same engine witch would explain why opera and chrome have the same issue. In addition even when using incognito the issues persistent.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Error message in opera

[image]
Same as in chrome

Comment: What are “timeout errors?” Please [edit] your question with the exact message you are receiving from the browsers. Preferably attach a screenshot of the actual browser error and website you are trying to access.

Comment: I have added a image for opera it is the same error in chrome sometimes I get the error but sometimes I am able to go to the websites with no problem. This error for can happen for any website on the web.